# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' for conditional statement using AND

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, conditional-statements

i have a data set

```
Name   Verified   Happy

Gabriel  True      Yes
John     False     No
Daniella True      Yes
Gabriel  False     No
Elena    True      Yes
Gabriel False     Yes
```

Expected output:

```
Name   Verified   Happy  Gesture

Gabriel  True      Yes    Bye
John     False     No     Bye
Daniella True      Yes    Bye
Gabriel  False     No     Hi
Elena    True      Yes    Bye
Gabriel False     Yes    Bye
```

So the condition is if name is Gabriel AND she is not verified and if she is not happy then we will give gesture as "Hi".

What i have done:

```
df['Gesture'] =  np.where(df['Name'].eq('Gabriel') &df['Verified'].eq(False) & 
                 df['Happy'].eq('No'), 'Hi', 'Bye')
```

I also tried:

```
df['Gesture'] = ((df['Name'].eq('Gabriel') & (df['Verified'].eq(False) &  (df['Happy'].eq('No'))).map({True:'Hi',False:'Bye'}))
```

Still I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Can anyone tell where am i going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this is all you have tried, because I tried in my system, and I was unable to reproduce it. Which versions of Pandas and Numpy are you using?

Comment: Are you getting the expected output? @Pranjalya

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your problem. What's the output `df.head(5).to_dict()`

Comment: Pandas Version: 1.3.5, Numpy: Version: 1.21.6 @Pranjalya

Answer (score 0):

Try running this

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

names = ["Gabriel", "John", "Daniella", "Gabriel", "Elena", "Gabriel"]
df = pd.DataFrame(names, columns=['Name'])
df["Verified"] = [True,False,True,False,True,False]
df["Happy"] = ["Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes"]
df['Gesture'] =  np.where(df['Name'].eq('Gabriel') &df['Verified'].eq(False) & df['Happy'].eq('No'), 'Hi', 'Bye')
print(df)
```

Comment: Having the same error :(

Comment: Then the issue must be coming from your Pandas or Numpy version as @Pranjalya was saying

Comment: What versions are you using?

Comment: I am using Pandas Version: 1.3.5, Numpy: Version: 1.21.6 @Alvin

Comment: I've tried to run the code with Pandas 1.3.5 and Numpy 1.21.6 but it still runs fine. Not sure where the error is coming from. Si you're using python3?